# Xenforo on Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I recently bought an amazon ec2 Ubuntu server. I wanted to install xenforo onto it. I don't really know how to go about doing this. The server has an ipv4 address, and it's basically just like any other Ubuntu server. Do I need to install apache server?

Comment: I was also thinking about lamp

Comment: Go to their site and read about requirements: https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/dev/